# Bootstrap section padding issue

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following html: On the 3rd section there is no buttom padding after the button group. Why is that?

```
<section style="background-color:#e67e22">
    <div class="container">
        <h1>Edit</h1>
    </div>

 </section>

<section class="well" >
<div class="container">
    <label for="inventory-name">Inventory Name</label>
    <input type="text" value="@Model.InventoryName" autofocus class="form-control" id="inventory-name" />
</div>

</section>

<section >
    <div class="container">
    <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="Basic example">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Save Changes</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Add</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Post to Facebook</button>

        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
    </div>
</div>

</section>

<section>
<div class="container">

    <p>Hello</p>

</div>

  </section>
```

Comment: So add margin-top to the next element, the third section. The previous section has a well so it gives it spacing. The third section has nothing to give it spacing.

Comment: yeah I can add margin, but I wanted to make sure this is a natural result. I just don't want to start giving padding here and there not knowing if it was an issue.

Comment: can you add a fiddle?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/vphothisan/c7meLxf9/

Comment: As I said before, the first section has an h1, so you have a margin. The second section has a well which has padding AND margin. The third section has nothing to give it spaces.

Comment: yes I understand that the first time.  I am trying to avoid custom styling.  What would be a good tag to wrap around it or in replacement of custom styling? is that a bootstrap class I should use instead to get margins?

Comment: Your question was asking why there was no space there so I explained that. You can use a <br> tag but I think that's worse than using styles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Official [getbootstrap.com](http://getbootstrap.com) has also used there custom class to provide margin-top and margin-bottom.

[See this image to see developer view of the custom class they used](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xHSdJ.png)

Comment if you are not getting...!